# How does OpenVZ know a VE's distribution

Tags: linux, virtualization, configuration, openvz

With OpenVZ you assign a VE's hostname (among other things) from the host node (HN) using `vzctl set CTID --hostname myhost --save`. It then sets this in `/etc/vz/conf/CTID.conf`. During startup of the VE, a distribution-specific file in `/etc/vz/dists` is consulted containing pointers to files in `/etc/vz/dists/scripts`. Those are distribution-specific scripts for editing the VE's config files, for instance if the VE uses Debian or Ubuntu, the hostname is written to `/etc/hostname`. The same happens with the IP address, for example.

My question now is: How does OpenVZ know which file in `/etc/vz/dists` to use? Does it somehow derive the distribution name from the template's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of vzctl, I figured out how it works. It actually does derive the name from the name of the template. When starting up the VE, at some point a method in `lib/dist.c` is called:

```
static int get_dist_conf_name(char *dist_name, char *dir, char *file, int len)
{
      char buf[256];
      char *ep;

      if (dist_name != NULL) {
            snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s", dist_name);
            ep = buf + strlen(buf);
            do {
                  snprintf(file, len, "%s/%s.conf", dir, buf);
                  if (stat_file(file))
                        return 0;
                  while (ep > buf && *ep !=  '-') --ep;
                  *ep = 0;
            } while (ep > buf);
      [...]
}
```

There it removes dash delimited parts from the end of the name, each time looking for a match. The template I was looking at is `arch-2010.05-x86_64-minimal`, so here it first tries `arch-2010.05-x86_64-minimal.conf`, then `arch-2010.05-x86_64.conf`, then `arch-2010.05.conf`, until it finally finds a file named `arch.conf` holding the pointers to the scripts for updating Arch's configuration files.